# AngularJS code is giving back error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.logout = function () {
    //var auth_token = $cookieStore.get('auth_token');
    Auth.delete({
      'auth_token': $cookieStore.get('auth_token')
    }, function(data){
      $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
      $cookieStore.remove('auth_token');
    });
```

When this called it given me an error:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array
z/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:6:450
t/</f[d]/q<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular-resource.min.js:8:1
De/e/l.promise.then/J@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:101:87
De/e/l.promise.then/J@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:101:87
De/f/<.then/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:102:259
Yd/this.$get</h.prototype.$eval@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:113:28
Yd/this.$get</h.prototype.$digest@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:110:109
Yd/this.$get</h.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:113:360
m@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:72:452
w@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:77:463
ye/</B.onreadystatechange@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:79:24

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js
Line 92
```

Comment: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array. If you go to the URL given in your error it explains the problem. Your $resource is configured to return an array but the server is sending an object, or vice versa. Change your resource configuration, there is an isArray property that you can set to true or false accordingly.

Comment: use non-minified version of angular to know the error details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a common problem. The delete method of resource model is expecting a json response which must be an object but your server is returning the json data in array format. So you have two options either change your server code to respond the json object data or change your resource model something like:

```
var Auth = $resource('/your-server-url', {}, {
    delete: {
       isArray: false
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
SA